# For each loop how to export data to new line in CSV file?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I'm scraping data from multiple URL's and the data received was split to words. With the help of for loop I'm trying to append the data to empty list and creating data frame and later exporting to csv file. The problem is when exported to csv it is overwritten the previous column and I can see only one column. How to export the data to each row from each iteration.

```
import urllib.request
from inscriptis import get_text
import pandas as pd
from googletrans import Translator
from time import sleep

url_list = pd.read_csv("/home/user/Downloads/warrior_categories.alcohol.csv")
urls = url_list['domain']


def dataextraction():
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for url in urls:
        final_url = 'http://' + url
        try:
            html = urllib.request.urlopen(final_url).read().decode('utf-8')
            text = get_text(html)
            extracted_data = text.split()
            refined_data = []
            SYMBOLS = '{}()[].,:;+-*/&|<>=~0123456789'
            for i in extracted_data:
                if i not in SYMBOLS:
                    refined_data.append(i)
            print("\n", "$" * 50, "HEYAAA we got arround: ", len(refined_data), " of keywords! Here are they: ",
                  "$" * 50, "\n")
            print(type(refined_data))
            empty=[]
            for data in refined_data:
                empty.append(data)
            df.append(empty)
        except:
            pass

    df.to_csv('alcohol.csv', index=False)

print(dataextraction())
```

Comment: you should defind `DataFrame` out of for loop and keep appending `empty`  in `df` in for loop and export csv out of for loop as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question required more explanation but what i understand is you want to show all columns build in for loop in csv it can be done something like that

```
import pandas as pd


def dataextraction():
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for url in urls:
        final_url = 'http://' + url
        try:
            html = urllib.request.urlopen(final_url).read().decode('utf-8')
            text = get_text(html)
            extracted_data = text.split()
            refined_data = []
            SYMBOLS = '{}()[].,:;+-*/&|<>=~0123456789'
            for i in extracted_data:
                if i not in SYMBOLS:
                    refined_data.append(i)
            print("\n", "$" * 50, "HEYAAA we got arround: ", len(refined_data), " of keywords! Here are they: ",
                  "$" * 50, "\n")
            print(type(refined_data))
            empty=[]
            for data in refined_data:
                empty.append(data)
            df.append(empty)
        except:
            pass

    df.to_csv('alcohol.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: its not creating any csv file.

Answer (score 1):

If you need just add a records from loop

```
# need to describe the columns. Just empty df with columns
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['name'])
# let's imaging here is your loop with one record
for i in range(5):
    # you conditions here... if blablabla.... and append if you need
    df = df.append({'name': str(i) + 'name'}, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

If you need to add a `df` from loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['name'])
for i in range(5):
    # here is a new df
    tmp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'name': ('{i}_{k}_name'.format(i=i, k=k) for k in range(i))})
    # you conditions here... if blablabla.... and concat if you need
    df = pd.concat([df, tmp_df], ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Hope this helps